# не удается подключится по hdbc к mysql в android studio

Tags: java, android, mysql

Здравствуйте, хелп, своими силами не получается законнектиться к БД по hdbc.

В манифесте доступ к инету открыл, драйвера вроде норм стоят,в runnable поместил. в чем проблема не могу понять , в Idea похожий код работает а тут надо как-то по другому.
Выдает кетч експшн в потоке.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbtest?characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false";
private static final String username ="root";
private static final String password ="root";
private static final String driver ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
public Connection connection;
final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
Potok mPotok =new Potok();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mPotok.run();
}
private class Potok implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        try{Class.forName(driver);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Vse ok potok idet ");
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Oshibka potoka ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Подключено такое 
`import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;`

```
Кодом не читабельно, вставляю весь стектрейс изображением
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: только что прочитал что на аднроиде в mysql проблематично коннектиться, нужно дампить. Это правда?

Comment: стектрейс приложите к вопросу

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov готово

Comment: загрузите явно драйвер для jdbc. а именно сделайте следующее Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov сделано, но все равно ексепшн)

Comment: исключение то же или оно не смогло драйвер найти в методе forName?

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov Я в принципе новичек, и в стактрейсе не силно еще нахожу проблематику, вот например сейчас красная строка новая 
? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'javax.naming.StringRefAddr', referenced from method 
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty.storeTo

 , что возможно говорит о драйвере, но наверняка, я сказать увы не могу

Comment: похоже каких то зависимостей нет, трудно сказать что то еще

Comment: во первых: подключена ли либа? во вторых: у вас что, база на самом устройстве?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прочитал что hdbc не шибко надежная штука поэтому,
Решил проблему без hdbc а с помощью json+php +xampp.

создал пермиты и закинул в корень
`$user = 'your_user';
$pass = 'your_pass';
$db = 'testdb';
$sql='select*from users';
$db = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die("Unable to connect");
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$response=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($response, array('name'=>$row[1],'age'=>$row[2],'email'=>$row[3]));
}
echo json_encode (array('server_response'=>$response));
mysqli_close($db);`

Потом в самом приложении json обьекты размещаются в текствью.
Полное обьяснение каждого шага в мануале у мужичка, кидаю сылку (это первое из 3 видосов https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOKgO09edyk)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String JSON_String;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
public void getJSON(View view){
    new BackGroundTask().execute();

}
class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
    String json_url;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        json_url="http://192.168.0.103/android/index.php";
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url=new URL(json_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
            while ((JSON_String=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                stringBuilder.append(JSON_String);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(result);
    }
}
```